# Random background from ArrayList<Drawable>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

in my app i have this part of code for set a background image to a button!

```
private int [] [] double;
private List<Drawable> images;
----------------------------------------------------------
images = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1));
images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2));
images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img3));
images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img4));
images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img5));
images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img6));
images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img7));
images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img8));
-----------------------------------------------------------
button.setBackgroundDrawable(images.get(double[x][y]));
```

Now i' im trying to set random image to this button from this `ArrayList<Drawable>.` Is there someone who has some helpful tip for me?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you should make an arraylist of Integers and put the drawable id in there and access it with setBackgroundResource.

Example:

```
private List<Integer> images;

images = new ArrayList<Integer>();

images.add(Integer.valueOf(R.drawable.img1));
button.setBackgroundResource(images.get(double[x][y]).intValue());
```

This way it will consume less memory since now you are only storing Integers rather than Image Drawables, and it will be more efficient.

Comment: Eclipse give me back this error!
The method intValue() in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)
Solutions?

Comment: @MarcC check it out now

Comment: it give me back random images but i need to put in: 
int [] [] double; like without random images.get(double[x][y]) i just have similar code with my attempt:
int size = images.size();
int random = new Random().nextInt(size);

Comment: it give me back not a random backgroud ;) you deleted the random and it was like first version with ArrayList<Drawable>.

Comment: is a game like memory game! double[x][y] is for give me back the same cards!... If it isnt, it give me back a lot of different images not couple!!! =) =)

Comment: sorry i didn't understood it properly